# Unable to fetch the input property value- Angular

Tags: angular, input, components

todo.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import{ TaskService } from './../task.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo',
  templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo.component.css']
})
export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {
  chosenstatus="todo";
  todoService:TaskService;
  constructor(toDoS:TaskService) { 
    this.todoService=toDoS;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

todo.component.html

```
<app-task [sts]="chosenstatus"></app-task>
```

task.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TaskService } from './../task.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-task',
  templateUrl: './task.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task.component.css']
})
export class TaskComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() sts;
  todoService;
  constructor(toDoS:TaskService) { console.log(this.sts) /*here it shows undefined*/
    this.todoService=toDoS.getTasklist(this.sts);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

task.service.ts

```
export class TaskService {
   tasklist= [{taskname:"sample task",taskdetail:"This is a test task",status:"todo"}];
   filteredtask;
  constructor() { }
  getTasklist(chosenstatus){
    return this.tasklist.filter((e)=>{
      console.log('ngf'+chosenstatus); /*here it shows undefined*/
        if(e.status==chosenstatus){

          return e;

        }
    });

  }

  addTask(name,task){
    this.tasklist.push({taskname:name,taskdetail:task,status:'todo'});
  }



}
```

I am passing the variable (chosenstatus) from todo component to task component via Input property , but it does not gets send.It shows undefined. Please tell what mistake I am doing.

Comment: Can you create a plunker or stackblitz to show the error

Answer (score 0):

In your task component, rather than the constructor, try under:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.todoService=toDoS.getTasklist(this.sts);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use ngOnInit instead of constructor.

```
ngOnInit() { 
    console.log(this.sts) ;
    this.todoService=toDoS.getTasklist(this.sts);
  }
```

Comment: ok but why so ? Even constructor should run this when this component is initialized.

Comment: @YoYo, Ideally you should only handle the initialization in `constructor()` have a look at this: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence. Anyways, did it work?